# Populate data in existing PBIX file from C# app (Power BI Desktop)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to populate data to an exiting pbix file from an application written in C#.
As a result, I would like to be able to deliver the pbix file to the user with the updated data. 
Due to restrictions, I’m not able to use a different way to share data.
I can only upload (SFTP) each day the updated pbix file.
I am aware that one way to do it is to provide a CVS File along with the pbix file where the CVS file is updated which would force the user to refresh the pbix file on his own before she/he can use it.

I would like to accomplish that on my side and deliver a “ready-to-use” updated pbix file. Is that possible to make some operations on pbix from an external app written for example at C#?